# List<Map<String, Object>> group and reduce to Map<V1, V2>,

Tags: java, java-8

I got a json response named **`listResult`** with the form `List<Map<String, Object>>`, each `Map` has two important entry, it looks like the following:

`{
    key1:category,
    key2:num 
}`

Then, the `List<Map<String, Object>>` would show as the following:

```
[
    {
        key1:c1,
        key2:1 
    },{
        key1:c2,
        key2:2
    },{
        key1:c1,
        key2:4
    }
]
```

What I want to get is the following:

```
{
    c1:5, // 1 + 4 according to c1
    c2:2
}
```

With traditional way, the code would like this:

```
            Map<String, BigDecimal> topCount = new HashMap<String, BigDecimal>();
            for (Map<String, Object> topDataMap : listResult) {
                BigDecimal count = topCount.getOrDefault(topDataMap.get(ARTICLE_ITEM_CODE_KEY), BigDecimal.ZERO);
                topCount.put((String) topDataMap.get(ARTICLE_ITEM_CODE_KEY),
                        count.add((BigDecimal) topDataMap.get(VALUE_KEY)));
            }
```

The question is: **How can I achieve this with java8?**

========================

I forgot that I also need to sort the result map **by value** in the same stream.
I can make it with twice `stream()`, but I wonder is there a easier way with just once `stream()` ?

Comment: list.stream().map(map -> map.get("key1")).collect(Collectors.toList())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert

```
[{key1=c1, key2=1}, {key1=c2, key2=1}, {key1=c1, key2=4}]
```

into

```
{c1=5, c2=1}
```

with Java 8 streams, you do

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> topCount = listResult.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        m -> (String) m.get("key1"),
        m -> (BigDecimal) m.get("key2"),
        BigDecimal::add
));
```

*Full code*

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listResult = List.of(
        Map.of("key1", "c1", "key2", BigDecimal.valueOf(1)),
        Map.of("key1", "c2", "key2", BigDecimal.valueOf(1)),
        Map.of("key1", "c1", "key2", BigDecimal.valueOf(4))
);

Map<String, BigDecimal> topCount = listResult.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        m -> (String) m.get("key1"),
        m -> (BigDecimal) m.get("key2"),
        BigDecimal::add
));
System.out.println(topCount);
```

*Output*

```
{c1=5, c2=1}
```

---

**UPDATE** From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977743/listmapstring-object-group-and-reduce-to-mapv1-v2/51978048?noredirect=1#comment90907864_51978048):

> Furthermore, if I want to order the result map by value desc, how could I achieve it with the same stream?

A `Map` cannot be natively order by value, but you can sort the data, then build a new `LinkedHashMap`, which retains insertion order.

First, you have to build the `Map` as above, to get the value to sort by, then sort the map entries and build desired map:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> topCount = listResult.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        m -> (String) m.get("key1"),
        m -> (BigDecimal) m.get("key2"),
        BigDecimal::add
)).entrySet().stream()
  .sorted(Comparator.<Entry<String, BigDecimal>, BigDecimal>comparing(Entry::getValue).reversed())
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
                            (a,b) -> { throw new AssertionError(); },
                            LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Furthermore, if I want to order the result map by value desc, how could I achieve it with the same stream?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one solution.
The key is you should `map` first, transform your `Map<String, Object>` to target map `Map<String, BigDecimal>` with origin map's value.

```
    Map<String, Double> topCount = queryResult.getData().getResult().stream()
            .map(m -> new HashMap<String, Double>() {
                {
                    put((String) m.get(ARTICLE_ITEM_CODE_KEY), ((BigDecimal) m.get(VALUE_KEY)).doubleValue());
                }
            }).flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, summingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)))
            .entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Double>comparingByValue().reversed())
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

===========================

Thanks for @Andreas.
And further more, I also need to sort the result map. Based on @Andreas answer, I do it with the following code:

```
    Map<String, BigDecimal> topCount = queryResult.getData().getResult().stream()
            .collect(toMap(
                    m -> (String) m.get(ARTICLE_ITEM_CODE_KEY),
                    m -> (BigDecimal) m.get(VALUE_KEY),
                    BigDecimal::add))
            .entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<String, BigDecimal>comparingByValue().reversed())
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

But it use `stream()` twice. I don't know how to make it with just one `stream()`

Comment: Note that this anonymous class *hack* is considered an **anti-pattern**. If you want a short map creation, you can also use `Map.of` (Java 9).